# Addition numbers as a char* [C++] without string.h

Tags: c++, char, character, addition, subtraction

I want to add two numbers that are in char*.
For example:

```
char aux1[100];
char aux2[100];
char answer[100];

aux1="913";
aux2="88";

answer= aux1+aux2; //1001
```

Of course the last line is wrong.
I tried using atoi, but I cant use string library. I going to add numbers that cant join in int or long int. I can only use char* and the answer must be in char*.

The same for subtract "-". If is a negative number the symbol go to the first position 0.

I was thinking transform digit to digit and solve it, but I don't know.

Comment: -2928182727193929287218838283828432983 cant join into int

Comment: That won't even fit into a `long long int` or `int64`, either.  So, unless you use `float` or `double` instead, you will have to use an arbitrary-precision library that supports arithmetic operations. Handing things digit-by-digit is easy when the numbers are positive, but get tricky when negatives are involved. Best to let a pre-existing library do the hard work for you

Comment: That's why should use a char*. The number cant fit into long long int.

Comment: That is why you should use a pre-existing [arbitrary-precision library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C%2B%2B_multiple_precision_arithmetic_libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm. It may be familiar to you from elementary school:

- Pad the shorter string with leading zeroes so that lengths are equal.
- Let Carry be 0.
- Starting from the last index:

  - Convert the character in the current index of both input strings into the numeric value that the character represents. Add Carry and both input digits together. The result will be a number AB where A and B are digits (possibly 0).
  - Set output digit at current index to B.
  - Set Carry to A.
  - Repeat until the entire string has been processed.

I'll leave the handling of the negative numbers as an exercise.